# Description parameter to argparse.ArgumentParser() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have the following script:

```
import argparse

TEST_DESCRIPTION = """
This script issues the following commands:
    1. Command1
    2. Command2
    3. Command3
"""

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=TEST_DESCRIPTION)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

print(TEST_DESCRIPTION)

Without any option, the output is as I expected (with proper newlines and indentation)

```
# ./test2.py

This script issues the following commands:
    1. Command1
    2. Command2
    3. Command3
```

However, when I use the "-h" option, it seems the newlines and indentations are removed from  TEST_DESCRIPTION when it is passed to argparse.ArgumentParser().

```
# ./test2.py -h
usage: test2.py [-h]

This script issues the following commands: 1. Command1 2. Command2 3. Command3

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Is there anyway I can preserve the formatting of TEST_DESCRIPTION as it is written when it is passed to argparse.ArgumentParser().  (I tried making it a raw string, inserting \n, but no luck.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `RawTextHelpFormatter`, it's [right there in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#formatter-class):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=TEST_DESCRIPTION, 
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
```